# the correct way to get the content right of the img?

Tags: html, css

[image]

if the page structure is like the above. using HTML and CSS to get that. which way you will use?

some one told me:if you using float to both content (img,content), you must be fixed the width, the structure will lost its flexible, at the same time,you must solve problems caused by float. but i don't know the best way to get that,

Comment: Use `float: left` for containers of both the boxes above

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/). It's by Nicole Sullivan, who brought us the notion of OOCSS, and is perfect for this scenario.

This suggests to use `float: left` on the image, and `overflow: hidden` on the text to get the benefits of the overflow's interaction with floated content.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply `float : left` the image and I would give a `margin-right` to the `img` element so that if the image is not available (or optional) the text can start adjacent to the left margin of its container

then I would apply easyclearing techinique to the `img` parent

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using inline-block as I'm not a big fan of floating elements:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMXVW/)

Answer (score -2):

I would use `margin-left:` on the text to keep it away from the image.